# reserving space in browser layout for responsive images (preventing reflow)

Tags: javascript, image, css, browser, frontend

I have been making changes to make my site more responsive and, in general, this has gone well. However, I have run into one problem:

Before, I always used height and width attributes on img elements in order to **reserve space in the layout** for the images while the browser loads them in. This prevents the layout from jerking around while the browser loads and calculates the needed space for the image.

After making my images more responsive, however, by using `max-width: 100%` and taking out the height and width attributes, the browser no longer reserves space for the image (because it no longer knows how tall or wide the image is going to be in advance since I couldn't explicitly tell it)

My goal is to have responsive images that also take up their appropriate space in the page layout upon its initial load. Does anyone know of a solution for this?

***EDIT (SOLUTION)** -  [this is the best article I have found on the topic](http://web.archive.org/web/20161120085902/http://andmag.se/2012/10/responsive-images-how-to-prevent-reflow/). Nice approach!

Comment: Showing us your HTML could shine some light on the problem.

Comment: We can't really know how to help until we see the code that decides how big the images should be, when that code runs, the page HTML and how the images are inserted into the page.

Comment: How are you making the site responsive?  Are you loading different stylesheets based on width and height of the browser?

Comment: @jfriend00, that's just it, I don't want the code to determine how big the image should be explicitly, I want the browser to control this dynamically based on the available space for the image (which in turn is based on screen size). This is why the max-width: 100% technique is used.

Comment: @davehale23, for these images, the only technique I am employing is the max-width: 100% technique, which causes the image to scale to its largest possible (proportional) size within its available space.

Comment: @BrianFitzGerald - I don't think there's a solution to your question.  You're asking for the browser to know in advance how large your image is going to be and reserve the exact amount of space for it without telling the browser how big the image is.  But, the browser doesn't know how big the image until it downloads it so it doesn't know how much space to reserve.  This is not possible as you've described.

Comment: @jfriend00, I think you're right but I just want to make sure I'm not missing a possible workaround to this quandry from someone who knows more about responsive design than myself. This seems like a major drawback to responsive-image techniques and I feel confident that others have dealt with this in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer here is to prevent the vertical reflow by using the "padding-bottom trick". To make this technique work, you must know the proportions of the image in advance.

Thanks to Anders M. Anderson for [posting an excellent article](http://web.archive.org/web/20161120085902/http://andmag.se/2012/10/responsive-images-how-to-prevent-reflow/) on the topic. This is how it works:

1. Wrap your images in a div with a class of image-container (or similar), and provide the appropriate styles (below)
2. Secondly, style your images with absolute positioning and force them to fill the space of the container
3. Lastly, add another class to the image-container div according to the aspect ratio of the image. This aspect ratio class forces a padding-bottom onto the parent div, giving the container the correct height, and allowing your image to take up the expected space.

NOTE, if you're wondering why my class names (below) look weird, [check out "BEM"](https://getbem.com/introduction/), it's great.

```css
.responsive-image__container {
     position: relative;
     height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color:black;
  }

  .responsive-image__img {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width:100%;
  }

  .responsive-image__container--ratio-16-9 {
     padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 9/16*100 */
  }

  .responsive-image__container--ratio-4-3 {
     padding-bottom:75%; /* 3/4*100 */
  }

  .responsive-image__container--ratio-1-1 {
     padding-bottom: 100%; /* 1/1*100 */
  }

  /* and so on, for any aspect ratios you need to support */
```

```html
<div class="responsive-image__container responsive-image__container--ratio-4-3">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/300" class="responsive-image__img">
  </div>
```

Note, this also works for embedded videos which need to be responsive... AND take up their appropriate height in the browser to prevent content reflow, which is the entire point of this technique.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it.  It's not awesome, but works.   http://jsfiddle.net/78Lvc/11/

I changed the image tag to look like this:

```
<img src="http://fitzgeraldmedia.net/images/range1.jpg" id="img" imgWidth="467" imgHeight="700" onload="fixMyWidth()"/>
```

You'll notice that I have added some attributes and an `onload`.  You will have to add the attributes in code or by hand.  The reason that you need the height and width is because you need to know the height of the image to calculate the space required in JS.

Then inline, I have this code:

```
<script>
    //get the width of the browser right now
    var containerWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;
    //get the attributes that we have specified for this image
    var imgWidth = document.getElementById("img").getAttribute("imgWidth");
    var imgHeight = document.getElementById("img").getAttribute("imgHeight");

    //since the img is to be 50% of the container width
    var widthRatio = containerWidth / imgWidth / 2 ;

    //now set the height of the image
    document.getElementById("img").style.height = (imgHeight * widthRatio) + "px";

    //once the image has actually loaded, run this
    function fixMyWidth(){
        //this will make it 'responsive' again
        document.getElementById("img").style.height = "";
        document.getElementById("img").style.width = "";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question said:

> by using **max-width: 100%** and **taking out** the height and width attributes, the browser no longer reserves space for the image ...

I think the questioner did not use the `meta name="viewport"` in his "html" codes. Here is the code of a html file that have an **img** tag with height and width attributes that is also **responsive**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>img responsive</title>
    <style>
        .img {
          display: block;
          max-width: 100%;
          margin: 0 auto;
          height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://hamid-davodi.com/img/images/portfolio-preview.png" id="myImg" width="1441" height="758" alt="My Image" class="img">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum ipsa enim, magni asperiores officiis adipisci! Alias vero at nostrum tempore facilis temporibus provident quae quo illo, error eligendi in, odit, ducimus? Harum incidunt enim blanditiis veritatis tenetur, quam provident quae. Nulla in incidunt libero atque nemo, pariatur dolore perspiciatis ut vero maiores praesentium iste fuga quis possimus repellendus a placeat, repudiandae officiis fugiat! Facere necessitatibus a aspernatur assumenda aliquam nisi et suscipit nemo reiciendis enim! Ipsa quos illo atque? Repellat iusto officia expedita harum odio consequatur sequi eos quas eum delectus molestias nulla ut impedit rem temporibus neque, provident. In alias, repellendus repellat culpa officiis accusamus enim perspiciatis non nihil omnis necessitatibus obcaecati provident unde odit ipsa impedit corporis, numquam, adipisci nisi porro, fugiat consectetur et aspernatur similique. Similique beatae vel deleniti voluptatum ratione pariatur nihil numquam dolores soluta tempora incidunt magni nobis ipsum non minus quo, necessitatibus modi temporibus saepe harum, iure iste animi fugit! Natus maxime aliquam qui. Esse nisi, rem. Vitae, illo, ratione. Fugit, nesciunt ratione modi minima itaque ipsum obcaecati magnam laboriosam amet quae suscipit optio reprehenderit aperiam dolore! Vel necessitatibus odit, molestiae ea perferendis dicta recusandae quibusdam maxime, natus autem voluptatum, iusto alias distinctio vero in sint, incidunt. Unde, esse nemo voluptatum ab est blanditiis expedita consectetur itaque repellat eveniet. Porro placeat harum, tenetur nam sed ipsa, est, maxime tempore obcaecati dolores possimus magni deleniti illum facere pariatur nostrum? Ipsa nemo officia ipsam pariatur neque sed suscipit ducimus dolores temporibus, aperiam perspiciatis soluta quibusdam sequi cum, illo totam labore hic nesciunt laborum odit. Eius rem saepe delectus necessitatibus eligendi, beatae officiis placeat quaerat illo! Laboriosam eaque, repudiandae consequatur repellat blanditiis recusandae adipisci amet iste aperiam alias magnam itaque dicta illum praesentium eum totam fugit atque ad ducimus soluta voluptatibus odio nostrum beatae dolorum? Assumenda tempore officia facilis fugit earum unde, illo ab dolorem nulla quos temporibus cumque rerum sed deserunt quaerat molestiae aut soluta, iste, doloremque distinctio! Id optio, dolorem perspiciatis, corporis distinctio eos enim perferendis. Cum sint placeat sequi cupiditate quas sunt saepe beatae aut molestias quod modi sit temporibus consequuntur ab repudiandae ut eius dolores aliquam iusto quibusdam ea dolore exercitationem, recusandae perferendis. Repellendus molestiae eum, iste, commodi explicabo officia adipisci enim cumque exercitationem minus veniam optio numquam, alias doloribus modi voluptates consequatur eius. Quia ut incidunt reprehenderit cupiditate repudiandae tempore nam dicta, quo iure exercitationem odio sapiente laboriosam non ducimus dolore quis labore dolores, odit eius quam nesciunt, voluptas a laudantium magnam veritatis. Reprehenderit magnam veniam, voluptatum facere a blanditiis, soluta cumque sint, corporis eligendi, neque quod. Nemo odio repudiandae non vel sapiente. Fugiat ipsum soluta consequatur, sunt nulla placeat quis, in quia a iure commodi est, maxime libero cum laborum magnam deserunt nihil. Obcaecati, rerum ducimus dolor esse expedita doloremque impedit voluptas blanditiis soluta officiis provident placeat, beatae, sint reiciendis. Aut ratione atque, tempore officia eligendi magnam obcaecati quis quia, soluta excepturi facere iure autem explicabo assumenda fuga a sequi suscipit! Praesentium, aspernatur nulla asperiores incidunt numquam eum eos dolor accusantium.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

You can test it also in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/davoodi68/full/RwYwoOV).

Answer (score -3):

I wouldn't take height and width attributes out, just try setting them to auto.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but setting them to auto does not solve the problem. The browser still does not reserve the appropriate space for the image in the layout.