# Slick.js: Hide slider until images have loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using [Slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), how does one hide the slide until the images have loaded or at least the first image has loaded? I tried using `init` but couldn't get it to work. Nothing is outputted to the console, either.

```
var $slider = $('.slider').slick({
    fade: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
    speed: 1000
});

$('.slider').on('init', function(slick) {
    console.log('fired!');
    $('.slider').fadeIn(3000);
});
```

I also tried `window load`, but that didn't fix it either.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.slider').fadeIn(3000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q5r9ertw/

Answer (score 74):

I know it's an old question, but this worked for me in a similar situation, when the problem was that all slides were displayed at once and this looked horrible and jumpy.

The solving is pure CSS.

First, you add CSS to your slick slider wrapper:

```
.your-slider-wrapper {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
```

After slider is initialized, the slick adds .slick-initialized class to the wrapeper. You can use this to add:

```
.your-slider-wapper.slick-initialized {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;    
}
```

Hope this helps someone who stumbles upon this question as I did.

Comment: Works great but you have a typo in visibility rule :).

Comment: Clean and simple, this should be the answer.

Comment: This one works best and should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 20):

Make sure to bind the `init` event before initializing slick.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/b5d5mL7p/

```
var $slider = $('.slider')
        .on('init', function(slick) {
            console.log('fired!');
            $('.slider').fadeIn(3000);
        })
        .slick({
            fade: true,
            focusOnSelect: true,
            lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
            speed: 1000
        });
```

Comment: In the fiddle , have you noticed that initial rendering is not proper, and when you click on the button , then it works fine afterwords. ?
How can we fix that ?

Answer (score 7):

Slick adds the class 'slick-initialized' to the wrapper that you call 'slick' on.

Set all slides except the first to `display:none` on initial load and you get the slider at its correct height, with no jumping on slick load.  When slick is initialized, you want them all back to `display: block`.

`CSS`

```
.slide img {
  height: 600px;
  width: auto;
}
.slide:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
.slider.slick-initialized .slide:not(:first-of-type) {
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work in my case. Image is loading (appearing on the screen from top to bottom), but  .slick-initialized class is already set

Comment: It did work for me.  Images loaded near the top of the HTML, Slick not loaded and invoked until just before the </body> tag.

Comment: {time passes} OK...  it only *almost* works for me.  Sometimes all is well; other times not.  After a certain amount of *vin exceedingly ordinaire,* I realized that my Slick call was inside a jQuery `$( document ).ready`, which fires when the DOM is ready.  It really needs to be inside `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"` so Slick doesn't start until the *pictures* have been loaded.

Comment: There is still the difficulty that responsive images cause layout rendering problems.  A solution is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458297/reserving-space-in-browser-layout-for-responsive-images-preventing-reflow).

Answer (score 4):

Try below code.

```
#your-slider .slide:nth-child(n+2) {
  display: none;
}
#your-slider.slick-initialized .slide {
  display: block;
}
```

***Note**: You need to add `slide` class to each slide in your slider*

**Codepen demo**: https://codepen.io/rohitutekar/pen/GRKPpOE

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that before slick slider is initialized you might see all your slides, since the markup is simply a div list. I think hiding the slider and then fading it looks not very smooth when the page is loaded. I would try this instead:

```
<style>
.slickSlider{
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

where the height should be set to the height of your images and then

```
  $('.slickSlider')
    .on('init', function(slick) {
        $('.slickSlider').css("overflow","visible");
    })
    .slick({
        fade: true,
        focusOnSelect: true,
        lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
        speed: 1000
    });
```

This has also the benefit that the dots and arrows only appear when slider is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

None of this gave me required result i.e show slider in such a way which doesn't disturbs the look of website. I finally figured it out myself with this generic code. In case anyone is looking for solution do try this.

```
.yourslickclass > div:not(:first-child)
 {
   display: none;
 }
```

Comment: This will work for single slide sliders. For multiple slides you have to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I have this code:

```
.slider-slick:not(.slick-initialized) .blog-slide-wrap:not(:first-child)
 { 
      display: none
 }
```

Structure my slick slider

```
        <div class="blog-slider slider-slick">
        <?php
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="blog-slide-wrap">
                <img src="<?= get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'blog-slider') ?>">
                <div class="blog-text-wrap">
                    <h2><a href="<?= get_the_permalink() ?>"><?= get_the_title() ?></a></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `visibility: hidden` on your carousel wrapper by default, and add `.slick-initialized { visibility: visible; }`.

Once slick is initialized, it adds the slick-initialized class to the wrapper which will bring its visibility back.

Comment: Didn't worked for me. Slick adds .slick-initialized class before the slides being ordered properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use display none `<div class="slider" style="display:none;">` in your slider then display it when page is ready `$('.slider').css("display", "block");` and then run the slide js code.

Example Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider').css("display", "block");
  $(".center,.opti_gallery").slick({
          dots: true,
          infinite: true,
          centerMode: false,
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          arrows:false,
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="slider" style="display:none;">
   <div>
      <img src="img1.png">
   </div>
   <div>
      <img src="img2.png">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add class "slick-slide" to each slide